# Get row count using group by in entityframework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a TheaterMovieShowTime entity in that entity I want to get the row count by grouping on a particular column say TheaterMovieDetailID .

Here is my entity :

```
public class TheaterMovieShowTime
{
   public int TheaterMovieShowTimeID { get; set; }
   public int TheaterMovieDetailID { get; set; }
    public int TheaterShowTimeID { get; set; }

    public virtual TheaterMovieDetail TheaterMovieDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual TheaterShowTime TheaterShowTime { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my TheaterMovieDetail entity:

```
public class TheaterMovieDetail
{
    public int TheaterMovieDetailID { get; set; }
    public int TheaterID { get; set; }
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }

    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public virtual Theater Theater { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TheaterMovieShowTime> TheaterMovieShowTimes { get; set; }
}
```

I try this :

```
 var p = _theaterMovieShowTimeService.GetAllTheaterMovieShowTime()
            .GroupBy(x => x.TheaterMovieDetailID)
            .Select(x => new TheaterMovieShowTimeSummaryViewModel
            {
                TheaterName = x.FirstOrDefault().TheaterMovieDetails.Theater.TheaterName,
                MovieName = x.FirstOrDefault().TheaterMovieDetails.Movie.MovieName,
                NoOfShows=???????? // get the no of rows here
            });
```

How do I get NoOfShows here that is no of rows grouped by TheaterMovieDetailID .

Would appreciate any help offered. Let me know if you need any other information to help answer this question

Comment: In general, it actually helps to have *meaningful* variable names instead of `x`. So, `GroupBy(showTime => showTime.TheaterMovieDetailID)` and `Select(showTimesForMovie => new Theater...` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use linq `Count()` function:

```
var p = _theaterMovieShowTimeService.GetAllTheaterMovieShowTime()
    .GroupBy(x => x.TheaterMovieDetailID)
    .Select(x => new TheaterMovieShowTimeSummaryViewModel
    {
        TheaterName = x.FirstOrDefault().TheaterMovieDetails.Theater.TheaterName,
        MovieName = x.FirstOrDefault().TheaterMovieDetails.Movie.MovieName,
        NoOfShows= x.Count()  // get the no of rows here
    });
```